# Multiple EditText with same setOnEditorActionListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I my app i could have at a certain time "x" EditText fields. I add dinamicaly new EditText so the number of them can vary. I want to have one listener for all of my EditText that can tell what view ( edittext ) has been changed.

I search a bit and found :

```
 private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher()
```

but the problem with this is that it does not have a parameter View v to tell me what view is currently changed like :

```
OnFocusChangeListener listener = new OnFocusChangeListener() .....public void onFocusChange(final View v, ....
```

Also found :

```
OnEditorActionListener
```

that has a :

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, (parammeter)
```

But it does not trigger when user is typing, finish typing...

Is there a listener that can be used for all of my edittext ( no mater their number ) and has a View v parammeter ?

Sorry for my english ...

Any help will be good

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that fits better for me :

I create a class :

```
public class Whowho implements TextWatcher
{
   private View view;
   private Activity act;
   public Whowho(EditText view, Activity activ) 
   {
      this.view = view;
      this.act=activ;
   }
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {}
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
   {
       EditText ed = (EditText) act.findViewById(view.getId());
       ....
       AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
       RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
       .....
       ((TextView) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ok, 0, 0, 0);
       ((TextView) view).setText(...);
```

}
    }

And i use it like this :

```
ed.addTextChangedListener(new Whowho(ed,CLASS.this));
```

For me it work great. Hope it will help others to